# Not understanding slicing in Python

Tags: python

In the below code I want to print the first two values using slicing. But I get only one value in the output. Is there anyone who can understand what is happening?

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
b_list = a_list[1:2]
print(b_list)
```

Output is: `[2]`

Comment: List indices start at 0, not 1, so the slice `[1:2]` is certainly not going to include the first element of the list...

Comment: Right.  `a_list[0:2]` says "start with element #0, and end just before element #2."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing

Comment: Did you search "[slicing in Python](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=slicing+in+Python)"? You are [expected to do some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking people to give you a solution.

Comment: See [Hans' answer](/a/509297/4518341) on the linked duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is `:` in Python?** It is an operator for slicing a list and it is an alias for `slice(start, end, step)` function.

**How can I use it and how it works?** When you use it with a list such as `[1,2,3]` like `[1,2,3][0:2]` you get all elements from 0th to first. In fact, 2 is excluded.

And please mind that array indices start from 0, so 1 is the 0th element of the list:

```
[1,2,3][0] == 1 # True
```

And if you want to get all elements you can use `[1,2,3][0:3]`.

Two more points:

1. There is another part: `step` like `[start:end:step]` and you can specify step size, for example `[1,2,3,4][0:4:2]` will give you `[1,3]`
2. You can omit any part of a slice: `[:4]` means `[0:4]`, `[0:]` means `[0:last_index+1]`, and `[:]` means `[0:last_index+1]`

Comment: Technically, it's not an operator. Check out the discussion on [Slice "colon operator" nomenclature](/q/33520674/4518341)